# How can I determine the range of the function $f : Z \to Z$ which is defined as $f = \{ (x, 4x + 5) : x \in Z \}$

Tags: functions

I'm told to find the domain, codomain, and range of the function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ which is defined as $f = \{ (x, 4x + 5) : x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

I can determine the first two, but I'm struggling to define the range. I tested out a few values of $x$, such as:

$f(-2) = -3$

$f(-1) = 1$

$f(0) = 5$

$f(1) = 9$

$f(2) = 13$

I don't really see a pattern here, though. They're not primes, and they're not just all odd integers, but rather a subset of odd integers. I also can't factor anything from $4x + 5$ to say, for instance, that it's the set of all multiples of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

How can I express the range for this function? Any intuition/procedure one can use to arrive at an answer would be appreciated, as I don't see one myself.

Comment: Well, you could just say the range is the set of integers which are $5$ more than a multiple of $4$.  Since $5=4+1$ it would probably be more typical to say the range was the set of integers which are $1$ more than a multiple of $4$.

Comment: It's exactly half the odd numbers! It's all the multiples of 4 but with 5 added to them.

Comment: Or you could write it as $\{ y \in \mathbb{Z} : y \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \}$ if you're familiar with that notation.

Comment: It is the set $$4\mathbb Z+5$$

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm familiar with the modulo operator, but I'm having trouble interpreting what the set you defined means.

Comment: @AleksandrH It's just set builder notation, as in $\{ x \in A : P(x) \}$ is the set of elements of $A$ which satisfy $P$.  Some people would also write it as $\{ x \in A | P(x) \}$, or in this case, $\{ y \in \mathbb{Z} | y \equiv 1\pmod{4} \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks! I understand the set builder part, though the modulo (and how you arrived at that expression) is what's throwing me off :)

Comment: @AleksandrH OK, $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$, or equivalently that $n$ divides $a-b$.  For example, $13 \equiv 5 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: Oh, I get it, so it's the set of all $y$ that, when they are divided by $4$, result in a remainder of $1$? Also, this may seem like a stupid question, but how would that work for negative integers? For example, $-3/4$ has a remainder of $-3$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

For range of the function, you can write -

$4x+5=4(x+1)+1=4k+1$ Since $x \in \mathbb Z \, \implies  k \in \mathbb Z$

Thus, range of the given function is all the integers of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: Thank you! It says I can accept an answer only in 11 minutes. Question: couldn't I also write it as, say: $4x + 5 = 4(x - 2) + 13 = 4k + 13$ for some $k \in Z$, and any other such variations? Edit: I guess I could, seeing as how no matter how you write it, $k$ still remains an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Welcome @AleksandrH, for your question - Yes, definitely you can write many variations, and can also answer accordingly, for example : Range of this function is all the integers of the form $4k+13$, and it's absolutely correct, but that seems to be a bit awkward, since we do not write a remainder greater than the divisor itself. For example -  question "What is the remainder when 53 is divided by 10" so, here both 13 and 3 are correct answers, but we will generally answer 3.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.